# Cairo: Drawing with clip set gives fuzzy ornaments

Tags: linux, canvas, gtk, cairo

I am programming a tool that has a custom canvas in it derived from Gtk::DrawingArea. The drawing does not happen directly on the DrawingArea. I have two Cairo::Surfaces. One surface is the Background (mostly an image) and the other surface is stuff that was drawn by the user.

When the user draws, I do not redraw the whole surface, I just set a clip on the Cairo context to only draw what is necessary. The Problem is, that when I have the clip set on the image background I can see a white frame around the clipped area. Is there a flag or a workaround, so the image would look good instead of having fuzzy frame ornaments around it?

Comment: Are you using a rectangular clip? It should not "divide" pixels in half.

Comment: Yes I do. What do you mean?

Comment: If you have no calls to cairo_scale() or cairo_rotate() and if you only clip by rectangles constructed by cairo_rectangle() with integer coordinates, then clipping shouldn't cause any fuzzyness. http://cairographics.org/FAQ/#clipping_performance Do you do something else than this?

Comment: Ah thank you. I use doubles atm to clip, i will cast them to int then. Tried it out! Works like a charm! Thank you very much.